# two similar polygons in google maps have very different areas?

Tags: google-maps

I have a polygon tool and a shape tool on my Google map. I want the user to be able to calculate the area of a shape using both tools. The problem is that I get vastly different values for area on shapes that are the same size(or very close). For example, the polygon area result will be 552523.74, while the rectangle area result will be 27.57.

Here is my code so far:
**Rectangle**

```
google.maps.event.addListener(newShape, 'bounds_changed', function() {
var area= rectArea(newShape.getBounds());
}

function rectArea(bounds){
   var sw = bounds.getSouthWest();
   var ne = bounds.getNorthEast();
   var southWest=new google.maps.LatLng(sw.lat(), sw.lng());
   var northEast=new google.maps.LatLng(ne.lat(), ne.lng());
   var southEast = new google.maps.LatLng(sw.lat(),ne.lng());
   var northWest = new google.maps.LatLng(ne.lat(),sw.lng());
   console.log('rec coords: '+ northEast +',' + northWest +',' + southEast +',' + southWest);
        area=google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea([northEast,northWest,southEast,southWest]);
        return area;
    }
```

**Polygon**

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', function (polygon) {
        var coordinates = (polygon.getPath().getArray());
        area=google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea(coordinates);
        console.log('poly coords: '+ coordinates);
        console.log('Polygon '+ this.id +' Area is: ' + area);
    });
```

Comment: Note to editors: don't correct code samples in questions without knowing what you're doing! The anonymous editor (who was then approved by someone who should know better) corrected the code *in a way that removed the problem the OP is asking about*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the array used for computing the area of the rectangle  has a wrong order, it has to be e.g.:

```
[northEast,northWest,southWest,southEast]
```

**demonstration of the difference:**
[image]

Comment: That was the trick! - but where does it say that? I've looked at that API guide until my eyes crossed! :P

Comment: Added an image which should clarify the difference between the areas

Comment: That makes sense - I guess I was going too fast.